# Implementing DRM Protection for Content Stored on GCP Cloud Storage in a Koa and Apollo GraphQL Full-Stack Application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo-server, koa, react-fullstack

I have developed a full-stack application using Koa and Apollo GraphQL, and I have stored all of my website's content, including videos and photos, on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Cloud Storage. Now, I'm looking to implement DRM (Digital Rights Management) protection to prevent unauthorized downloads and screen recordings of my content. Can anyone provide guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this within my application?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated in advance. Thank you!

I attempted to use the Gumlet library for DRM with ReactJS from the documentation provided at https://docs.gumlet.com/docs/drm-with-reactjs. However, it appears that this library does not provide support for TypeScript.

Is there a way to make the Gumlet library work with TypeScript in a ReactJS project? If so, could you please provide guidance or an example of how to set it up with TypeScript? If not, are there any alternative libraries or solutions that do support TypeScript and DRM with ReactJS?

Thank you for your help!